# Searching data frame by indexes and exporting information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have indexes in *range* data frame. I want to use them to find values in test dataframe and extract values from into new data frame. 
My current code is:

```
d = []
for index in _range_.index:
    d.append((test.loc[[index],:]))
```

```
_range_ data set:
              a
2334   0.097946
3345   0.098201
3357   0.091249
3486   0.098214
5862   0.097946
6873   0.098201
6885   0.091249
7014   0.098214


_test_ data set:
            0         1         2         3         4         5         
0      4.187268  4.261664  4.329495  4.458864  3.071192  3.652938
```

Comment: could you attach some example data/input/output?

Comment: I have attaches examples.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how you are using the two dataframes together, and what your expected output is

Comment: So, I want to use indexe from df _range_ to find/extract rows in df _test_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the two dataframes together on their common index using 'inner' then keep only the **test** columns.

```
cols = __test__.columns

df = __range__.join(__test__, how='inner')

df=df[cols]
```

If you have an overlap of colum names between the two dataframes, attach an lsuffix='_l' or something similar to ensure the **range** columns are ignored.

I'm unable to test this code on for your example though, it might be worth reading over this for future posts https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example